# Back wheel cannot turn.

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel

I have an ONYX ONE 29' cruiser bike. It's a really big bike and it has rear wheel brakes. 
I recently removed the back wheel with a power tool, for I tried to remove it with a wrench, and it wouldn't come off.  I think I might of stripped the inner axle of the back wheel hub however. 
Now, I have installed the wheel, it turns when I'm off it, but when I get on it...I cannot pedal. I cannot pedal even when I'm off the bike. 
The back brake mechanism is off to the other side. I can put it back on...but I don't think that is the problem. ??? Can anyone help out.

Comment: You have to reattached the arm for the coaster brake. It might help if you could post a picture of what the bike looks like now.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to take the bike to a bike shop.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back.  What I was trying to do was install a 2 stroke engine...well, I'm in the process of doing so...just haven't been able to spend the time I need with it.  But, I have installed the gas engine bracket on the rear wheel, the reason I had to take it off.  
When I looked at it as I was installing it back on to the frame...that the hub seemed "lose."  It looked like the axel was coming out...or it would slide.  But now that its on it doesn't look bad.  lol!! I will take a picture and post it when I get a chance...yes...this must be done.  thank u

Comment: batman...thanks.  Wonder dog sounds like me in that he enjoys a challenge.  This is Not to say that you don't enjoy one from time to time, mind you. 
I'll keep you all posted.  Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that the spokes on this bike might not be "strong" enough to handle the pull or torque from the 80cc gas motor I'm installing.  
I think I need a wheel with thicker spokes in order for the bike to handle my weight and the pull of the engine to work safely on this bike. 
I'd appreciate any leads you may have...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken apart a coaster hub since I discovered girls but I remember there was a number of friction plates like a wet plate clutch that did the braking. These are actuated by forcing them together when you press the pedal in reverse. I don't recall details but I wonder if there might be a left handed thread in the assembly that was tightened in getting it apart. The other possibility is that the axle is stripped as you suggest.